# How do I bind dependent drop down lists in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I need a way to bind multiple drop down lists that are populated based on their parent node.

`RootDDL <- child <- grandchild[]`

The code looks something similar to

```
<FormView DataSoureceID="rootDatasource">
    <DropDownList ID="RootDLL" AutoPostBack="true">
        <!--items-->
    </DropDownList>
    <DropDownList ID="child" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="ChildDataSource" />
    <SqlDataSource ID="ChildDataSource" />

    <DropDownList ID="grandchild" DataSourceID="GrandChildDataSource" SelectedValue='<%# Bind('SomeFieldInRootDatasource') %>' />
    <SqlDataSource ID="GrandChildDataSource">
        <SelectParameters>
            <ControlParameter ControlID="child" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </SqlDataSource>
    <Button Command="Update" />
</FormView>
<SqlDataSource ID="rootDatasource">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="SomeFieldInRootDatasource" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="SomeFieldInRootDatasource" />
    </UpdateParamters>
</SqlDataSource>
```

Changing the rootDDL works, unfortunately when the Child selectedvalue changes the grand child `<%# Bind %>` tries to rebind but cannot as it the FormView is no longer acting as a container.

It fails with

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Is there any solution to this problem that will not require me to add event (multiple) handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `hiddenfield` for each child `dropdownlist` that I then bound with the value I needed.  I created a generic `indexchange handler` to then update the `hiddenfeild` with the desired result.  This results in the bound field not being updated by a datasource (avoiding the rebind system call that was causing the issue in the first place).

Not sure if this is the best solution but it should work for most cases.